# react-router redirect query string

Tags: react-router

I am trying to use react-router 2.X to include a redirect logic.

```
    <Route path="albums" component={AlbumList}>
      <Redirect from=":albumId" to='/photos/' query= { {'album_id': ':albumId'} } />
    </Route>
```

it seems like :albumId can be extracted from the url in "from" and "to" properties but not in query, how can I use the value of :albumId in query property. Thanks

Comment: where you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: If anybody knows the answer it would be nice to know as well. Looking for a solution.